# Datatype.nat versus nat?

Tags: coq

The problem is I declared an inductive function in [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr) and want to test it.  But I’m having an error with my `Check` line which is:

```
Inductive natprod : Type :=
   pair : nat -> nat -> natprod.

Check pair(3 5).
```

Here is the error:

```
Error: Illegal application (Non-functional construction): 
The expression "3" of type "Datatypes.nat"
cannot be applied to the term
 "5" : "Datatypes.nat"
```

I really don’t understand what the problem is? What’s the difference between Datatype.nat versus nat?

P.S.: i have written an inductive function for "nat" (named also "Inductive nat"), could it be there a problem with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pair` is a function of type `nat -> nat -> natprod`.

So to apply it, you use function application syntax:

```
Definition threefive := pair 3 5.
```

So to test its type:

```
Check (pair 3 5).
```

`nat` and `Datatypes.nat` are the same type. Coq is just being more verbose in certain messages in order to avoid confusion (it tells you "the nat as defined in the Datatypes module", in case you have defined another version somewhere else...)

---

And I guess this message appeared because you defined your own `nat`, so you'll probably be in trouble if you do:

```
Check (pair 3 5).
```

Because 3 and 5 are parts of `Datatypes.nat`, not of the `nat` type you created.

So you should use the constructors of your own `nat` type.

Comment: And how can i do that ?

Comment: I mean, it is also named nat (my inductive function)

Comment: What is your definition of `nat`?

Comment: `Inductive nat : Type :=
     | O : nat
     | S : nat -> nat.`

Comment: Then you can use `S (S (S O))` to mean `3` for your type, etc.

Comment: Yes, but if i want to use integers ? How could i change that ?

Comment: What do you mean by integers? If you want to use the built-in natural numbers, just use `Datatypes.nat`. If you want to use your own type, but still be able to use the notation for numbers (that is, write `3` instead of `S (S (S O))`), then I'm not sure Coq has a facility for borrowing the notation, but you can create a coercion `coqNatToMyNat : Datatypes.nat -> nat` and make it implicit I guess.